# Better understanding program detected as virus w/ sandbox

Tags: virus, anti-virus, malware, sandbox

My AV solution detected a program as a virus.  Can someone point me in the right direction to learn more about the following points?

1) What exactly about the program was determined as the triggering factor?  If a classification is given, such as "Trojan.something", do any AV solutions say exactly what the triggering factor was to place it in that category?

2) I know some people sandbox malware and learn what it's impact would have been.  What is the best way to go about this?  I assume there are better methods than simply making a trash VM with a debugger installed?

Comment: If you have the name of the virus, some of the AV program locations will give an in-depth analisis of the method of operation , file effect and registry change (of the virus itself). Names (plural) can be aquired from an upload to VirusTotal, then using a search engine.  Then skipping all the (more or less) fraud locations that list anything to SEO and sell thier program.  You may find most of the stuff already analised , or a very close variation of.

Comment: 1. I think you will find that all AV companies keep their detection algorithms secret (to prevent virus authors working out how to bypass detection). 2. Best left to the experts ;)

Comment: 1) Yes, there are some sites that can tell you more about malware, how it works and what it does. For example see [SecureList](https://securelist.com/description/). 2) Probably the best way is using virtual machines. Take HDD snapshot before and after running malware, compare and get what was changed.